# Failed to connect to Cloud Foundry endpoint

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, router, cloud-foundry

I've setup Cloud Foundry locally with Bosh Lite and uploaded stemcells and releases as described [here](http://elsoufy.blogspot.com/2015/02/installing-cloud-foundry-v2-locally-on.html). When I try use my CF installation and connect to the API endpoint I get a connection refused error as follows:

```
$ cf api --skip-ssl-validation https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io
Setting api endpoint to https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io...
FAILED
Error performing request: Get https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io/v2/info: dial tcp
10.244.0.34:443: connection refused
```

I can reach the `10.244.0.34` ip address (and all addresses listed below) from my machine:

```
$ ping 10.244.0.34
PING 10.244.0.34 (10.244.0.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.244.0.34: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.47 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.0.34: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.84 ms
64 bytes from 10.244.0.34: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=2.28 ms

--- 10.244.0.34 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.842/2.201/2.473/0.264 ms
```

Here is the list of the different VMs running on the cloud:

```
$ bosh vms
Deployment `cf-warden'

Director task 6

Task 6 done

+------------------------------------+---------+---------------+--------------+
| Job/index                          | State   | Resource Pool | IPs          |
+------------------------------------+---------+---------------+--------------+
| api_z1/0                           | running | large_z1      | 10.244.0.138 |
| etcd_z1/0                          | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.42  |
| ha_proxy_z1/0                      | running | router_z1     | 10.244.0.34  |
| hm9000_z1/0                        | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.142 |
| loggregator_trafficcontroller_z1/0 | running | small_z1      | 10.244.0.150 |
| loggregator_z1/0                   | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.146 |
| login_z1/0                         | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.134 |
| nats_z1/0                          | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.6   |
| postgres_z1/0                      | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.30  |
| router_z1/0                        | running | router_z1     | 10.244.0.22  |
| runner_z1/0                        | running | runner_z1     | 10.244.0.26  |
| uaa_z1/0                           | running | medium_z1     | 10.244.0.130 |
+------------------------------------+---------+---------------+--------------+

VMs total: 12
```

What I'm missing to successfully establish a connection the endpoint?

Comment: Can you try running `curl https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io/v2/info`?

Comment: I get a connection refused on port 443 !

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to CF services not properly started, I had to use [bosh cck](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/blob/master/docs/bosh-cck.md).